# Server 2008 Net Send or Msg?

Tags: windows-server-2008

I have a Windows 2008 server running as a domain controller. The details are as follows:

```
Domain: corp
Server Name: oxygen
```

The workstations are all running Windows XP SP3 and have fixed IP addresses.

I am trying to use the `net send` functionality to be able to send simple messages to either individual machines/users and also to all machines. This is so I can send a message to a user to alert them about something, or likewise alert everyone of something such as the server being rebooted.

Is this possible using Windows Server 2008? If so, what would the command be?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Net Send has been replaced with the "msg" command.  So typing "MSG /?" at a command prompt on Server 2008 or Windows 7 gets you,

MSG /?

MSG {username | sessionname | sessionid | @filename | *}
    [/SERVER:servername] [/TIME:seconds] [/V] [/W] [message]

- username            Identifies the specified username.
- sessionname         The name of the session.
- sessionid           The ID of the session.
- @filename           Identifies a file containing a list of usernames,
                    sessionnames, and sessionids to send the message to.
- - Send message to all sessions on specified server.
- /SERVER:servername  server to contact (default is current).
- /TIME:seconds       Time delay to wait for receiver to acknowledge msg.
- /V                  Display information about actions being performed.
- /W                  Wait for response from user, useful with /V.
- message             Message to send.  If none specified, prompts for it
                    or reads from stdin.

However, you're out of luck using msg to send to Windows XP clients unless you take advantage of some third party tool like [WinSent Innocenti](http://www.winsentmessenger.com/innocenti/)

Answer (score 1):

The "Net Send" command was really deprecated in Windows 7/2008, but, there is a better option for this platform. Use a script made to adapt the MSG.EXE command to the old style "NET SEND". It won't work with Windows 2003/XP (Just with Vista/7/2008), but it's simple and effective. Try this out:

http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/A-net-messenger-script-for-810f8331

Detailed explanations on how to use it:

http://pedrofln.blogspot.com/2011/08/net-messenger-script-for-windows-72008.html

Answer (score 1):

If you've moved on to Vista, or Windows2008 and go looking for the Net Send command, you aren't going to find it. This is because the command has been replaced with MSG.EXE. To launch the command: click on the Start button, type CMD in the search box and press Enter. The Command Prompt window will appear where you can send a message using MSG.EXE. For additional information about MSG.EXE, type msg /? at the command prompt and press Enter.
Or your may choose a business-level LAN messenger like BigAnt Corporate Messenger for an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, the net send command has been deprecated in W2K8.

Answer (score 0):

There are several suggestions:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues/thread/17ab8b3c-2320-40a1-a377-aa76fdad7351/

http://windows7forums.com/windows-7-support/36444-net-send-replacement.html

But it is off by default and won't be coming back.