# "Net Send" command into Microsoft server 2008 r2

Tags: windows-server-2008, security, windows-server-2008-r2

I remember with the old windows server was able to send messages with the command "NET SEND", now I am using "Windows 2008 R2" and this feature is not active.

Can you give me some additional suggestions to send messages to clients of my domain.

From the forums I read that it possible use the MSG command, but it is not very clear.

Domain Name: Domain

Workstation Name: PC1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct, Net Send no longer works in 2008 and above.  You can use the MSG feature as you've already found out.  Here is a great post on our own forum that will help you:

[Server 2008 Net Send or Msg?](https://serverfault.com/questions/216478/server-2008-net-send-or-msg)

[This is also a great resource for some examples and syntax usage.](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/commandlinereference/p/msg-command.htm)

You may also want to make sure that this reg key...

> HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\AllowRemoteRPC

... [(see the solution section here)](http://blog.umito.nl/2010/02/20/solution-to-msg-exe-error-5-getting-session-names.html/comment-page-1) is set to 1 for all computers that you will be sending messages to; this is mainly for workstations vs. servers, but some servers need this key set to 1 as well.